# Image overlapping with pause - skrollr

Tags: jquery, html, css

You can see here an [example](http://juanaguiar.es/skrollr/examples/pausing.html) (a close approach of what I want to achieve but not complete at all)

This is an explanation of what I'm trying to achieve:

1. See the image
2. Scroll down but still see the image for a few seconds (just maybe 2 sec)
3. Then the user sees the image that was below overlapping the image that was static.
4. Again: See the image > Scroll down and still see the image and after 2 sec > Then the image that was below overlaps the previous one.
5. Repeat and so on...

I have been reading the documentation but don't understand it a lot. Any help?

This is the markup:

```
<div data-0="transform:translate(0,0%);" data-1200p="transform:translate(0,-100%);">
    <div class="img-box">
        <img class="fittobox" src="images/1.jpg" alt="1" width="1280" height="800">
    </div>
</div>

<div data-0="transform:translate(0,100%);" data-100p="transform:translate(0,0%)" data-_box-100p="" data-_box-200p="transform:translate(0,-100%)">
    <div class="img-box">
        <img class="fittobox" src="images/1.jpg" alt="1" width="1280" height="800">
    </div>
</div>

<div data-_box-100p="transform:translate(0,100%);" data-_box-200p="transform:translate(0,0%);">
    <div class="img-box">
        <img class="fittobox" src="images/1.jpg" alt="1" width="1280" height="800">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using [skrollr plugin](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/)

Answer (score 2):

Sets the top offset using `window.scrollTo(0, top)` on dektop for updating the internal state in case of loop scrolling.

```
skrollr.init({
    easing: {
      //your code
    },
    render: function(data) {
        //Loop back to top 
        if(data.curTop === data.maxTop) {
            this.setScrollTop(0, true); 
              //will return first image when you reached to last
        }
    }
});
```

skrollr will jump to the new position without any kind of transition. By default the global smoothScrolling setting applies.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't your second slide behaving the way you wanted?

Have a look at this [simple parallax scrolling tutorial](http://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/), it might help you to understand Skrollr setting a bit better.

Also refer to [Skrollr.js infographics](https://raw.github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/master/guide/anchor-position-guide.pdf), it's a more visual way to see how the different data attributes affect timing and animations.

Comment: Yeah the second is behaving like I want but I just can't make it with the first and the third (and so on...) I'm not understanding the way the plugin works..

Answer (score 1):

This is a working demo:

http://dinhquangtrung.net/demo/skrollr/Pausing.htm

```
<div 
data-100p="transform:translate(0,0%);" 
class="skrollable skrollable-between" 
style="-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0%);">
    <div class="img-box" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden;">
        <img class="fittobox" src="./Pausing_files/1.jpg" alt="1" width="1289" height="805.625" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -70.8125px;">
    </div>
</div>

<div 
data-0="transform:translate(0,100%);"
data-100p="transform:translate(0,100%);"  
data-200p="transform:translate(0,0%)" 
class="skrollable skrollable-between" 
style="-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 100%);">
    <div class="img-box" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden;">
        <img class="fittobox" src="./Pausing_files/1.jpg" alt="1" width="1289" height="805.625" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -70.8125px;">
    </div>
</div>

<div 
data-0="transform:translate(0,100%);"
data-300p="transform:translate(0,100%);"  
data-400p="transform:translate(0,0%)" 
class="skrollable skrollable-before" 
style="-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 100%);">
    <div class="img-box" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden;">
        <img class="fittobox" src="./Pausing_files/1.jpg" alt="1" width="1289" height="805.625" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -70.8125px;">
    </div>
</div>

<div 
data-0="transform:translate(0,100%);"
data-500p="transform:translate(0,100%);"  
data-600p="transform:translate(0,0%)" 
class="skrollable skrollable-before" 
style="-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 100%);">
    <div class="img-box" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden;">
        <img class="fittobox" src="./Pausing_files/1.jpg" alt="1" width="1289" height="805.625" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -70.8125px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I can explain this thing in case you don't want to read the documentation:

```
<div 
data-0="transform:translate(0,100%);" // when top = 0, translate the image position by 100% down.
data-100p="transform:translate(0,100%);"  // when top = 100, still in the position translated 100% down.
data-200p="transform:translate(0,0%)" // when top = 200, move position to origin position.
```

The same thing with other pictures, only the first picture is special because it doesn't need to move anywhere.